# Lookup refs allowed for old values in datomic db.fn/cas

Tags: datomic

I try to use the folloing db.fn/cas transaction which contains lookup refs for both the old and the new value:

```
 [[:db.fn/cas id :task/state [:task-state/name "locked"] [:task-state/name "pending"]]
```

However it fails with:

```
{:e 17592186045792, :a :task/state, :v-old [:task-state/name "locked"], :v 17592186045558, :db/error :db.error/cas-failed}
```

(I verified that both lookup refs exist)

Does this mean that lookup refs are not allowed for old values?
Or did I miss some Point ?

Answer (score 0):

Lookup refs for the old value are not allowed when using `:db.fn/cas`, but you could make a custom tx function that supports lookup refs quite easily